# How to notice incoming delete commit, if I don't want files to be deleted?

Tags: git

Suppose, I am pulling from origin where there are many new commits including commits that delete files. How to find out the files easily, so I can do 'git rm --cached ' and add them to .gitignore beforehand. I got some of my IDE specific config files deleted this way.

Is there any other solution to handle such scenario than to look through the commits?

Comment: Not entirely sure what you're asking about here, why would adding those files to `.gitignore` change anything? If the files are already tracked, and the incoming commits delete them, they will still be deleted.

Comment: Is this a recurring situation you're expecting, or just a one-shot thing? In the latter case, just clone your local as a backup, and restore them afterwards. In the former case, there's something amiss in the overall repo setting since these files should already be ignored everywhere I guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this if you *avoid* `git pull`.

Remember that `git pull` means *run `git fetch`, then run a second Git command*.  The `git fetch` step is safe: just run it yourself.  The *second* command, usually `git merge`, is the one that may delete some of your work-tree files.

Once you have the commits—that's the `git fetch` step—you can *inspect* the commits to see if they will delete any of your existing tracked files.  To do so, just compare your current index to the target commit you want to merge, with the `--name-status` option:

```
git diff --cached --name-status origin/master
```

for instance.  You can add `--diff-filter=D` to check specifically for files that would be *deleted* by moving to `origin/master`.

If this says that your file(s) will be deleted, you can do your own `git rm --cached`, commit the result, and repeat the `git diff` to verify that they will no longer be deleted by the merge; then just run:

```
git merge origin/master
```

to do the second half of the `git pull`.